# Is there a native way to access the scope inside a range from inside a function?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In my template I use a range with a param like this:

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.myParam }}
---
fieldOne: $value.fieldOne
fieldTwo: $value.fieldTwo
myFunc: {{- include "myFunc" $ }}
{{ end }}
```

I want myFunc to get access global values (`.Values.global.*`) AND the scoped variables like `$value.fieldOne` and `$value.fieldTwo`. Is this possible?

If I don't pass myFunc `$` it won't have access to globals. If don't pass it `$value` it won't have access to the range scoped values.

And I'd like to maintain the standard `.Values.global.*` referencing syntax for accessing globals inside myFunc- I don't want to create my own special map object the function has to read differently.

Currently I am doing this:

```
myFunc: {{- include "myFunc" (merge $ $value) }}
```

Then in myFunc I can access this:

```
{{- define "myFunc" -}}
# Get globals in the usual way
{{- .Values.global.myGlobal }}
# Get my scoped values for the current iteration
{{- .fieldOne }}
{{- .fieldTwo }}
{{- end -}}
```

Is this the only way to do this? It seems to work reasonably well, but I want to confirm there isn't a builtin like `.`, but for range scoped variables I can use inside myFunc.

## EDIT

I discovered an issue with my approach, it appears calling merge inside the function is mutating the root map.

For example doing this:

```
# helper function
{{- define "myFunc" -}}
# Get globals in the usual way
someGlobal: {{- .Values.global.myGlobal }}
# Get my scoped values for the current iteration
fieldOne: {{- .fieldOne }}
fieldTwo: {{- .fieldTwo }}
{{- end -}}

# In a template
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.myParam }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: $value.fieldOne
data:
    {{- include "myFunc" (merge $ $value) }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: $value.fieldOne
data:
    {{- include "myFunc" (merge $ $value) }}
{{ end }}
```

When I look at the outputted config maps the values returned from myFunc are the same. I also noticed I can do this:

```
# In a template
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.myParam }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: $value.fieldOne
data:
    {{- include "myFunc" (merge $ $value) }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: $value.fieldOne
data:
    someGlobal: {{ .Values.global.myGlobal }}
    fieldOne: {{ $value.fieldOne }}
    fieldTwo: {{ $value.fieldTwo }
{{ end }}
```

In the second `ConfigMap` the values are the same as the first. It's like calling merge inside myFunc is mutating the root map in place.

Ultimately I had to move the logic out of myFunc and call merge directly in the template to avoid this- doing that each iteration correctly gets its item's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Go `text/template` template only takes one parameter.  As with other programming languages, a function (template) can't access local variables in its caller, only things that are explicitly passed in parameters.

In short: the way you have it now is more or less as good as it's possible to do, given the constraints of the template language.  If you want to directly reference `.Values` then the single template parameter must be a dictionary object and not something else.

Comment: I discovered something that prevents me from doing it the way I tried. I updated my post. Be curious to know why its mutating the map like that.